# How exactly can I use shark to profile my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, shark

I want to use Shark on OS 10.5 to do some basic profiling of my iPhone game (Open GL ES + Objective C).  How exactly can I do this?  I've read tutorials but they are too verbose for me after a full day of coding at work and a few hours of iPhone development afterwards.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. Build app and launch on device
2. Launch Shark
3. From the Shark menu, select Sampling->Network/iPhone Profiling
4. In the Shark window, select the radio button "Control network profiling of shared computers".
5. Select your iPhone in the list and optionally configure the profiling session
6. Press Start to begin profiling, and Stop to end

After that, viewing the profile results is pretty straightforward, assuming you've looked at other profilers before.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 13):

Shark will only work for iOS devices running version 3.x

As of iOS 4.x, SHARK support has been removed from the OS, with no plans to bring it back.
Apple recommends using Instruments instead.

Comment: I'm presuming the "Time Profiler" template what shark provided.  At least for me, this accomplishes the task.

Answer (score 0):

Right From iOS 4, support for Shark is stopped. INstead we have to use Time Profiler available as part of the Instruments.

A discussion on Apple's Dev forums give information about this:

https://devforums.apple.com/message/243237#243237