# Why does Shark not list my iPod touch in the devices list?

Tags: iphone, performance, shark

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326078/how-exactly-can-i-use-shark-to-profile-my-iphone-app/1371528#1371528) Brian explained how to connect Shark with the device. I do it exactly this way, but Shark never lists my device. Even if Xcode launches my app on it and the app runs. I get console Logs and everything. It communicates with the mac. But Shark doesn't see it. What could cause this? Snow Leopard, btw...

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617677/what-can-i-do-when-shark-does-not-find-my-device

solved the problem for me. The device was running iPhone OS 2.2. It worked until I upgraded to Snow Leopard.

I also had to reinstall CHUD tools from the SDK 2.2 package as well (despite having reinstalled them from the CHUD 4.6 package). Then Xcode could not find the device until I rebooted it too.